# "Member cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead" error when using class reference

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, add-type

(i did check the similarly named questions, the case is different)

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=netframework-4.8 .

The subject method is `static` .

So i try to get it from the class, but still get the error .

Powershell

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'

public class sc {
    public static int init(int v) {
        
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(v);

        return 1;
    }
}

'@
[sc]::init(1000) | Write-Host
```

Comment: Please [edit] question to show "i try to get it from the class" case (showing case that you know should not work makes no sense to me)

Comment: `CurrentThread` is the instance reference through which you're trying to call the `static` method `Sleep()`.  Change it to just `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(v)`.